# Delphi FMX "swipe" not left or right gesture

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, gesture

I work with Delphi 10.3 and up.
I want to handle a "swipe" left or right.
By swipe I understand not left and right (I already implement that).
Is like "left + move down" in the same gesture. (like a diagonal)
Is there such a gesture in delphi or I have to implement myself code in this manner?

Comment: What about semicircle left and semicircle right?

Comment: nope. not working.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Have you followed the procedure to enable a gesture on a control using the gesturemanager and with hittest set to true? (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Gestures_in_FireMonkey)

Comment: yes. The "left" and "Right" gesture are working. But only working when you draw a exactly orizontal line. (left or right), when you are drawing a "diagonal" line, not working.I have implement the same code on semicircle left and semicircle right, but no succes.

Comment: I had the same trouble when implementing a left-right / right-left gesture. It took my users quite some time to master it.